# PlayFramework 2.5.4 unable to import package javax.persistence

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.5

I set up project with PlayFramework and using sbt plug-in as-

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")
```

To use JPA with hibernate I set built.sbt as

```
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJpa,  
  "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % "1",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.5.Final"
   )
```

But Still I have compilation error for not locating package javax.persistence

```
[error]   symbol:   class ID
[error]   location: package javax.persistence
[error] import javax.persistence.ID;
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
```

Same is working with older versions. Help me to debug and correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue in your import statement

```
[error] import javax.persistence.ID;
```

Change the above import statement to `import javax.persistence.Id;`